# How can i run same application between two macs?

Tags: macos, applications, software

I work in a small office where we share same jobs. We need to purchase another Mac desktop and somehow connect the 2 so we can both use the same program at the same time and it will update automatically (basically real time). Example: quickbooks multi user, multiple accounts: we can both be working in quickbooks in different accounts and they sync together. Hope i am make sense. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Each application needs to be designed for sharing.  You need to check on each application's ability to share.

Robert

Comment: Oh, Quickbooks was an example of sharing.

Comment: Oh, the edit was correct, but I do not know how to get the edit back.

Answer (score 2):

Two things to research when you purchase apps.

1. Are you licensed to run two copies on two different Macs a the same time. Generally OK for home use and not for business use. App Store licensing means if you get the App from Apple's store, you know the terms clearly. If not - you'll need to know how the vendor work it.
2. Just save the working files to a server or set up sync. For some things, like collaborating on a spreadsheet - you can use iCloud / Google Docs / OneDrive / box.com / SmartSheet / etc... - for others, there is no sharing - the file gets locked and you'll have to move things after.

It's really up to the implementation on how a document is saved whether your workflow will be possible or need a lot of workarounds / hacks or just fail. Quickbooks probably has both a sync and online version, but check with them to be sure or wait for someone who uses it - they might have an awesome answer, but I wanted to answer in general.